# How do I start Modern UI apps (calendar and mail) minimized when Windows 10 starts?

Tags: windows-10, email, calendar, modern-ui

When I log onto Windows 10 I would like both the Calendar and Mail applications to start minimized.

I can make them start automatically by:

1. Clicking on the Windows icon
2. Clicking on "All apps"
3. Finding the app I want
4. Clicking and dragging it to my Startup folder (found by running `shell:startup`)

and this works just fine.

However when I edit the properties of the shortcut and change the "Run" option to "Minimized" then this is completely ignored by Windows.

[image]

How do I get Windows 10 to run these Metro/Modern UI apps minimized?